# How do I ask a waitress to "wrap the rest of the food up" to bring home?

Tags: expressions, american-english, politeness, food

I went to a restaurant for a meal and didn't manage to finish it, so there was some food leftover. How do you politely ask a server/waiter/waitress to wrap the food up?

And is the expression "wrap up" correct?

Comment: I just ask for a doggy bag. (That works in Australia, anyhow.) But perhaps more generally, you could just ask if the leftovers could be put in a container to take away. (Restaurants where I live are always happy to oblige, however I put it.)

Comment: This is probably better asked on English Language Learners. But I think "wrap up" is fine. Other options are to ask for a box, or ask to box it up to go. I suspect but can't confirm that regional differences will apply heavily.

Comment: So I guess if I say "Can I have a doggy bag", then the waitress should know what I mean?

Comment: I'd say "Can I have a box, please?"

Comment: Also, you might want to look at the discussion here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239366/are-doggie-bags-still-asked-for

Comment: Generally, in the US, you ask for "a box", but it varies somewhat with the restaurant and the type of food.  The waitress may then offer to box up the food for you, or may return with a styrofoam container and let you place food in it as you wish.

Comment: Normally, when I go to restaurants and have leftovers, we ask for a take out box/container

Comment: I'd be careful about asking for a "doggy bag", as they might think it's actually for the dog and put all the leftovers into one bag (on the assumption that a dog doesn't care if the dishes are mixed up). If there's only one dish in question, then I guess it doesn't matter. :D

I'd suggest asking them to "wrap it up to go" or something similar.

Comment: @LiveMynd "doggie/doggy bag" is a euphemism, people ask for a doggie bag for several reasons: they actually do have pets; they spent a lot of money and they don't want to see it wasted; the food was too much, but they're happy to eat leftovers the next day etc..Restaurant folk know this, in fact, it's so well-known, people have stopped pretending the food is for their pets, and just come right out and admit it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I agree that many people who work at restaurants know that it is a euphemism, but can it be said of all restaurant workers? For example, if you were to dine at a restaurant with workers who are not native English speakers, there is a chance for misunderstanding. I think that asking for something to be wrapped up (to go) is less likely to cause a misunderstanding.

Comment: Serving staff who cannot speak English sufficiently well, shouldn't be serving English native speakers in the first place. It's simply bad business. But if their English is acceptable, I would have thought restaurant mangers instruct  them fully on their policy about leftovers—a very common occurrence—before unleashing them to the public. But maybe not everyone does. In the restaurant I used to work in, as a teenager, staff were properly trained.

Comment: And will it be okay to use: "Can I carry this food out" in AmE? @LiveMynd

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish I'd say it's more natural / acceptable to say "can I have this to go".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several options:

1) Could I have a to go container for this? Thanks.
2) I'd like to take this home.
3) Could you box this up for me?  Thank you.

I haven't heard "doggie bag" used in a long time, and to me isn't the impression I want to generate about the restaurant's food.

Sometimes, a server will ask you if you'd like to take the food home.  If not, just use one of the expressions I gave.

If you had a sandwich it makes sense to use "wrap up" but for some things, not.

Some fine dining places will not have take out containers and will politely decline.

Comment: Waitperson? Is that yet another term for server/waiter/ess? I thought *server* was the ubiquitous term in the US.

Comment: @Mari-LouA you're right...server is better.